# Node.js NTVS tool for the Visual studio

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-2012

[image: Following status show about in my visual studio]

Following status show about in my visual studio
I am new to the node.js... anyone help about the whole components installation ....
and helpfull tutorials about the starting with node.js via vs2012

Comment: follow this [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2013/11/22/node.js-tool-for-visual-studio.aspx) would help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper Install your NPM. And make sure that these versions listed are in package.json

```
Try This:  

 C:\Anthony\Demo\ExpressApp1\ExpressApp1>npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sane defaults.

See `npm help json` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg> --save` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
name: (ExpressApp1)
version: (0.0.0)
description:
entry point: (app.js)
test command:
git repository:
keywords:
author:
license: (ISC)
About to write to C:\Anthony\Demo\ExpressApp1\ExpressApp1\package.json:

{
  "name": "ExpressApp1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.4.4",
    "jade": "~1.1.5",
    "stylus": "~0.42.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
```